# Python gspread You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate

Tags: python, pandas, gspread

Hi I am using gspread with python and I want to share acreate google sheet as you can see below

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Connect to Google Sheets
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("gs_key.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

filename = "test_3"
sheet = client.create(filename)
sheet.share('my_email@gmail.com', perm_type='user', role='writer')
sheet = client.open(filename).sheet1
sheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
```

In some cases it works correctly but some other returns it returns the below error:

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."', 'errors': [{'message': 'Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalidSharingRequest'}]}

I can solve it and it it is weird as it sometimes works but not always
Thank you